# Filter out rows not containing certain words?

Tags: matlab, sorting, filter, cell-array

In MATLAB (R2015b) I have a very large Cell `C` containing multiple column vectors that can be simplified as:

```
C = [9000x1 double] [9000x1 double] {9000x1 cell} {9000x1 cell}
```

The last two columns in `C`, the two cells (9000x1 cell), the first cell-column contains the words `'GREN'` or `'BLU'`, and the second cell-column contains the words `'OVR'` or `'UNDR'` randomly.

So, in my mind, for example the first four rows of `C` may have the appearance of:

```
[ 123 54.3 'BLU' 'UNDR'; 125 51.3 'GREN' 'OVR'; 128 55.1 'GREN' 'UNDR'; 129 51.1 'BLU' 'OVR']
```

How can I filter out the rows that do **NOT** contain the words `'BLU'` and/or `'OVR'`? I.e. so that the example above becomes:

```
[ 123 54.3 'BLU' 'UNDR'; 125 51.3 'GREN' 'OVR'; 129 51.1 'BLU' 'OVR']
```

I've tried converting the cells into matrix format (cell2mat) and then filter the matrix without any luck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `strcmp`:

```
C = { 123, 54.3 ,'BLU', 'UNDR'; 125, 51.3, 'GREN', 'OVR'; 128, 55.1, 'GREN', 'UNDR'; 129,51.1,'BLU','OVR'};
idxs = strcmp(C(:,3),'BLU') | strcmp(C(:,4),'OVR');
CC = C(idxs,:)
```